# REACT JS email send with function

Tags: reactjs

i create standard function for email sending:

```
module.exports.test = function () {
    const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
    const log = console.log;
    
    // Step 1
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'mysmpt.com',
        port: 587,
        secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
        auth: {
            user: 'myUser', // TODO: your gmail account
            pass: 'myPass' // TODO: your gmail password
        },

    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
    });

    // Step 2
    let mailOptions = {
        from: 'fromEmail@mail.com', // TODO: email sender
        to: 'myEmail@mail.com', // TODO: email receiver
        subject: 'Nodemailer - Test',
        text: 'Wooohooo it works!!'
    };
    // Step 3
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            return log('Error occurs', err);
        }
        return log('Email sent!!!');
    });
 };
 this.test();
```

The problem, when I traying call function from another class, the email not sending and haven't errors.
when I run only function it send email.

I don't know what wrong I do

This is my class where i call SendEmail.js, and after function test() which i wrote before

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {test} from '../SendEmail';

class myClass extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        test();
        super(props);
    }   

    render() {
        return ('Some HTML'
        );
    }
}

export default myClass;
```

so, i cant see any errors, but email not sending.

Comment: The context isn't clear. How are you calling this backend code from React? Using an API? Using Nextjs? Please add more code and a clearer explanation of your current situation

Comment: Could you put your class implementation too?

Comment: try this order in the constructor
constructor(props) {
super(props);
test();
    }

Answer (score 0):

Nodemailer depends on Node.js.  React runs client-side in the browser. You cannot use Nodemailer directly from React.

Presumably you see no errors because you have Webpack configured to bundle Nodemailer in a way that features depending on Node.js fail silently.

If you want to use Nodemailer from React then you have to do it indirectly. Use Node.js to create a web service that uses Nodemailer. Then contact that web service using Ajax from your React application.

Comment: Can you send me some example how to do it?

Comment: "How to write a web service from scratch" and "Ajax 101" are both topics too broad for an SO question.